# how to normalize this below json using panda in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

[using this view.py query my output is showing something like this. you can see in choices field there are multiple array so i can normalize in serial wise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxRqT.png) **here is my json**

```
{"pages":[{"name":"page1","title":"SurveyWindow Pvt. Ltd. Customer Feedback","description":"Question marked * are compulsory.",
    "elements":[{"type":"radiogroup","name":"question1","title":"Do you like our product? *","isRequired":true,
        "choices":[{"value":"Yes","text":"Yes"},{"value":"No","text":"No"}]},{"type":"checkbox","name":"question2","title":"Please Rate Our PM Skill","isRequired":false,"choices":[{"value":"High","text":"High"},{"value":"Low","text":"Low"},{"value":"Medium","text":"Medium"}]},{"type":"radiogroup","name":"question3","title":"Do you like our services? *","isRequired":true,"choices":[{"value":"Yes","text":"Yes"},{"value":"No","text":"No"}]}]}]}
```

**this is my view.py**

```
    jsondata=SurveyMaster.objects.all().filter(survey_id='1H2711202014572740')
    q = jsondata.values('survey_json_design')
    qs_json = pd.DataFrame.from_records(q)
    datatotable = pd.json_normalize(qs_json['survey_json_design'], record_path=['pages','elements'])
    qs_json = datatotable.to_html()
```

Comment: Consider adding more details to what you want to achieve with a textual description and why your existing code "fails" (and what that means).

Comment: please click on the above link so you can able to find my error.

Comment: Yes, but what do you expect your output to look like? Do you want to split those lists with choices into multiple rows (one per choice)?

Comment: yes , but i dont know how to do,, can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and picture here's what I would do to go from the picture to something more SQL-friendly (what you refer to as "normalization"), but keep in mind this might blow up if you don't have sufficient memory.

Create a new list which you'll fill with the new data, then iterate over the pandas table's rows, and then over every item in your list. For every iteration in the inner loop use the data from the row (minus the column you're iteration over). For convenience I added it as the last element.

```
# Example data
df = pd.DataFrame({"choices": [[{"text": "yes", "value": "yes"}, 
                                {"text": "no", "value": "no"}], 
                               [{"ch1": 1, "ch2": 2}, {"ch3": "ch3"}]], 
                   "name": ["kostas", "rajesh"]})

data = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    for val in row["choices"]:
        data.append((*row.drop("choices").values, val))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["names", "choices"])
print(df)

    names                          choices
0  kostas  {'text': 'yes', 'value': 'yes'}
1  kostas    {'text': 'no', 'value': 'no'}
2  george             {'ch1': 1, 'ch2': 2}
3  george                   {'ch3': 'ch3'}
```

This is where I guess you want to go. All that's left is to just modify the column / variable names with your own data.